# Computing probability of completing a task composed of independent events

Tags: probability

This is a general question.  I have a task that is composed of 3 independent events: A, B, and C.  All are mutually exclusive and don't happen at the same time.  So first A, then B, then C.  I know the probability of completing each event with respect to time, I have the pdfs.  How can I calculate the probability of completing the task at hand with respect to time?

Answer (score 2):

First, a minor terminology correction: You can't really have independent and mutually exclusive events, as mutually exclusive implies that if one event happens, the others cannot happen, which makes them not independent. I think what you mean is that they are *sequential*, in that they happen one after another.

Since you have the pdf of each, what you want to calculate is the sum of the three random times: $T = T_A+T_B+T_C$. Depending on the exact form of your pdfs, you can try one of three approaches:

1. Recognize the sum as being equal to a particular distribution (e.g., sum of normals is normal)
2. Simulate the sum using Monte Carlo simulation
3. Analytically calculate the distribution of the sum by either multiplying the[characteristic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) of each pdf and then back-transforming to a denstity, or by directly performing two [convolutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Definition): $f_C*(f_A*f_B)$

I would recommend method 2 if you have access to a monte carlo simulator or know R or Matlab or any other numerical package. 1 is also OK...3 is a real pain unless you are lucky to be using simple distributions...in which case you will likely find a solution as per 1.